# Resources to consult alongside Griffiths?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, classical-electrodynamics, education

I'm trying to teach myself EM using Griffiths. However, the number of actual Physics problems in the book is limited, and since it takes a lot of practice to master a skill, I wanted to know if there are some resources from which I can practice ED from. For example, there are not many problems on solving Laplace's equation. Is there a book that I can refer to besides Griffiths for problems? I have Purcell but there isn't much about solving PDEs using separation of variables in Purcell.

Comment: I thought Griffiths has a whole chapter devoted to solving Laplace's equation.

Comment: If math were measured in tons then I would say there are tons of web resources on how to solve Laplace's Equation taught in many different ways including Youtube videos or MIT lectures and dozens of web articles or papers on the topic.